# Explicit expression for $(-\Delta)^s (|x|^2)$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n>2s$) and $s\in (0,1)$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

Do we know an explicit expression for $(-\Delta)^s (|x|^2)$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n>2s$) and $s\in (0,1)?$

Answer (score 2):

A classical result in distribution theory states that if $u$ is a homogeneous distribution on $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$ homogeneous distribution of degree  $d\in \bR\setminus \{-n,-n-1,\dotsc\}$, then it admits a unique extension to a distribution  on $\bR^n$.

For $\lambda \in \bC$  with positive real part  and $s\in (0,1)$  the distribution $(-\Delta)^su_\lambda$, $u_\lambda(x):=|x|^\lambda$, is homogeneous of degree $\lambda-2s$ and rotationally symmetric so it has the form  $C(s,\lambda)u_{\lambda-2s}$. Moreover  the function $\lambda \mapsto C(s,\lambda)$ is holomorphic.

To find the constant  $C(s,\lambda)$  use the Fourier transform $\newcommand{\eF}{\mathscr{F}}$  and we have
$$
\eF\big[   (-\Delta)^su_\lambda \big](\xi)= |\xi|^{2s}\eF\big[ u_\lambda\big](\xi).
$$
We  deduce that
$$C(s,\lambda)\eF\big[ u_{\lambda-2s}\big](\xi)=  |\xi|^{2s}\eF\big[ u_\lambda\big](\xi). $$

The Fourier transform of $u_\lambda$ is known and has the form
$$
\eF[u_\lambda]= K(\lambda, n)|\xi|^{\lambda-n}
$$ where $K(\lambda,n)$ is an *explicit* constant  involving  the Gamma  function (see e.g. volume 1 in Gelfand and Shilov's book on generalized functions).

We deduce that
$$C(s,\lambda)K(\lambda-2s,n)=  K(\lambda, n)\implies C(s,\lambda)=  \frac{K(\lambda, n)}{K(\lambda-2s,n)}. $$